# How go to a certain route without having a back icon?

Tags: react-native

I am currently learning React-Native. I have built a login page. After successfully login it should go to dashboard. However, when it lands to dashboard, the dashboard page has < Login on its left navigation. How to get rid of that

```js
  _handleLogin() {
    if (this.state.success) {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        title: 'Dashboard',
        component: Main
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this routing library: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Have a look at the gif on the detailed example page github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/… Im pretty sure this addresses your concern